# how much time will fibonacci series will take to compute?

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode, fibonacci

i have created the recursive call tree  by applying brute force technique but when i give this algorithm 100 values it takes trillion of years to compute..

what you guys suggest me to do that it runs fast by giving 100 values

here is what i have done so far

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n =< 1) {
      return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: "trillion of years" - what is your input ?

Comment: There are efficient algorithms to calculate fibonacci numbers. All you need to do is to google a little before asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7944249/367273

Comment: memoization technique could be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it also with a loop:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
for(int i = 2; i < 100; i++){
    int temp = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
System.out.println("Fib 100 is: "+b);
```

The runtime is linear and avoids the overhead caused by the recursive calls.

EDIT: Please note that the result is wrong. Since Fib(100) is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE you have to use BigInteger or similar to get the correct output but the "logic" will stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a "cache", where you save already computed Fibonacci numbers. Every time you try to compute

```
fib(n-1) /* or */ fib(n-2) ;
```

You would first look into your array of already computed numbers. If it's there, you save a whole lot of time.
So every time you do compute a fibonacci number, save it into your array or list, at the corresponding index.

```
function fib(n) 
{

if (n =< 1) 
{
  return n;
}
if(fiboList[n] != defaultValue)
{
  return fiboList[n];
}
else 
{
    int fibo = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    fiboList[n] = fibo;
    return fibo;
}

}
```

Comment: what you mean by defaultValue here

Comment: Whatever you choose, it could be -1 for example.

Comment: The idea is you create an array, and initialize each number in that array with a defaultValue, like -1. So if array[n] is -1, you know that that specific Fibonacci number has not yet been computed. If you find a different value at array[n], that's the result of fibo[n] so you don't have to go all the recursive way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by dynamic programming:

```
def fibo(n):
    dp = [0,1] + ([0]*n)
    def dpfib(n):
        return dp[n-1] + dp[n-2]
    for i in range(2,n+2):
        dp[i] = dpfib(i)
    return dp[n]
```