# JavaScript's Built-in Number() method seems to return an incorrect value

Tags: javascript, numbers, built-in

I've made a program to convert bases of numbers. I thought that, in the event that there are no characters `A-F` in the output, it would be convenient to return the number as a Number instead of a String (even though I'd be returning base 2 numbers as regular decimal numbers, whatever).

For some reason, when I converted `A3B2`<sub>32</sub> to Binary (which should be `1010000110101100100`<sub>2</sub> [[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A3B2+base+32+to+base+2) source]), I got `1010000110101100200`. There's a two in there, that isn't binary! The final line of code which returns the value is:

```
return (toBase <= 10) ? Number(result) : result;
```

This worked properly for basically all tests, until I decided to use that base-32 number above. I thought my program was doing the division/remainder step incorrect, so I had it print out the result just before it returns the value. It was correctly giving out `1010000110101100100`. So, I tested the `Number()` method directly in Chrome's console. This is what happened:

```
> Number("1010000110101100100")
> 1010000110101100200
```

Am I misunderstanding what the `Number()` method does? Why is it converting a string made up of all Ones and Zeroes to a number with Ones, Zeroes, and **Twos**?

Comment: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER > 1010000110101100100` returns `false`, so I'm not really surprised here.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376273/633183).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing when calling `Number("1010000110101100100")` is passing a string, which it is trying to turn it into a number, but that number is higher than JavaScript can count, which is 9,007,199,254,740,991 (also known as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`)

Basically, any number over 9,007,199,254,740,991 can't reliably be used because JavaScript uses [double-precision floating-point format numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) as specified in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Here's some examples, the following input numbers "should" be the same as the output, but aren't because they've gone over the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. Some are, but it's not reliable as demonstrated in the **Bonus Fun With LARGE Numbers** section below.

```
Number("9007199254740992") // 9007199254740992
Number("9007199254740993") // 9007199254740992
Number("9007199254740994") // 9007199254740994
Number("9007199254740995") // 9007199254740996
Number("9007199254740996") // 9007199254740996
Number("9007199254740997") // 9007199254740996
Number("9007199254740998") // 9007199254740998
Number("9007199254740999") // 9007199254741000
```

If you still want to convert hex to binary, you need to use `parseInt` and `Number.prototype.toString` and keep it as a string.

```js
const hex = "A3B2";
const binary = parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2);
console.log(binary);
```

#### Bonus Fun With LARGE Numbers

The following is true!

```js
console.log(9007199254740992 === 9007199254740993);
console.log(1010000110101100200 === 1010000110101100100)
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Comment: I believe the question was about specific nonstandard behavior when using `Number()`

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea this was a thing, but it's so obvious to me that it would be now that you explain it. 

I'm not using this for anything important, just to help some fellow first-years practice changing bases for an upcoming Computer Science Exam, so I think I'll just keep it as a string if it's above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

@AnonymusSB said is right. i want add few details to it.

So when you `Number(value)` it internally calls `ToNumber` to calculate the value. when you supply a string. it have a two step process to change it number.

1. First it calculate the `Mathematical value (MV)` of the string.
2. In second process it rounds up the calculated value.(when you exceed the limit of `Math.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` it round of the number).

```js
console.log(Number("9007199254740996"))
console.log(Number("9007199254740997"), "rounded down")
console.log(Number("9007199254740998"))
console.log(Number("9007199254740999") ,"rounded up")
```

[EcmaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1)