# How to find out below solution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a new web developer and need assistance generating a given output to a problem:

```js
var totalNumberofRows = 5; 
var output = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        output +=  i;
     }
    console.log(output+' ');
    output = '';
}
```

Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Expected Output:

```
1
22
333
55555
88888888
```

How would I be able to make my code produce the target output?

Comment: Why do you expect a non-sequential output when the loop is sequential?

Comment: Can you explain more about the expected output ? Right now, just doing ```console.log(1); console.log(22);...``` is a solution, but i guess it's not what you want

Comment: Are you supposed to output a fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944239/generating-fibonacci-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you intended something similar to the Fibonacci sequence?

```js
var totalNumberofRows = 5;
var output = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
    var next = fibo(i + 1);
    
    for (var j = 1; j <= next; j++) {
        output += next;
    }

    console.log(output + ' ');
    output = '';
}

function fibo(n) {
  let result = [0, 1];

  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    const a = result[i - 1];
    const b = result[i - 2];

    result.push(a + b);
  }

  return result[n];
}
```

Comment: I feel really bad because of this answer, you are computing again and again the same values, this is a typical use case of dynamic programming. Please edit with an optimised version, you just need to add an array holding the preceding values of the sequence, so that you dont have to compute it again. This edit will make the time complexity ~O(N) instead of something like ~O(n^2)

Comment: Thanks ! That's almost it ! The thing with your current solution is that you still compute again every value of the sequence for every new number asked to fibo(), you need put the array outside of the fibo() function so that it is remembered.

Answer (score 3):

For non-sequential numbers you could use an array with the [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8].forEach(n => console.log(n.toString().repeat(n)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the fibonachi sequence you can do :

```js
let current = 1
let last = 0

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(Array(current+last).fill(current+last).join(''))
  let toLast = current
  current += last
  last = toLast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8].map(item => console.log(item.toString().repeat(item)));
```